# Adding a commutative diagram (using tikzcd) to a beamer presentation on LyX

Tags: beamer, lyx, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'm using the “beamer-conference-ornate-20min.lyx” template on LyX and I'd like to add a commutative diagram as follows:

```
 \[\begin{tikzcd}   \ldots & {C_{p+1}} & {C_p} & {C_{p+1}} & \ldots \\  \ldots & {D_{p+1}} & {D_p} & {D_{p+1}} & \ldots     \arrow["{\partial_{p+2}}", from=1-1, to=1-2]    \arrow["{\partial_{p+1}}", from=1-2, to=1-3]    \arrow["{\partial_{p}}", from=1-3, to=1-4]  \arrow["{\partial_{p-1}}", from=1-4, to=1-5]    \arrow["{f_{p+1}}"', from=1-2, to=2-2]  \arrow["{\partial'_{p+2}}", from=2-1, to=2-2]   \arrow["{\partial'_{p+1}}", from=2-2, to=2-3]   \arrow["{f_p}"', from=1-3, to=2-3]  \arrow["{\partial'_{p}}", from=2-3, to=2-4]     \arrow["{f_{p+1}}"', from=1-4, to=2-4]  \arrow["{\partial'_{p-1}}", from=2-4, to=2-5] \end{tikzcd}\]
```

I've already verified this works just fine on a Book document class (after adding "\usepackage{tikz-cd}" to the LaTeX preamble). However, I get errors when I do the same on the beamer document class file and try to compile to a pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `\begin{frame}[fragile]` you can obtain the desired output.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile] %<-----------------------

\[\begin{tikzcd}   \ldots & {C_{p+1}} & {C_p} & {C_{p+1}} & \ldots \\  \ldots & {D_{p+1}} & {D_p} & {D_{p+1}} & \ldots     \arrow["{\partial_{p+2}}", from=1-1, to=1-2]    \arrow["{\partial_{p+1}}", from=1-2, to=1-3]    \arrow["{\partial_{p}}", from=1-3, to=1-4]  \arrow["{\partial_{p-1}}", from=1-4, to=1-5]    \arrow["{f_{p+1}}"', from=1-2, to=2-2]  \arrow["{\partial'_{p+2}}", from=2-1, to=2-2]   \arrow["{\partial'_{p+1}}", from=2-2, to=2-3]   \arrow["{f_p}"', from=1-3, to=2-3]  \arrow["{\partial'_{p}}", from=2-3, to=2-4]     \arrow["{f_{p+1}}"', from=1-4, to=2-4]  \arrow["{\partial'_{p-1}}", from=2-4, to=2-5] \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `a4paper` option is nonsense.

Comment: This solved it! Thanks a lot.